# Not able to inject SignalR IHubContext into class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm new to using SignalR and having troubles trying to inject IHubContext into a class. I get an exception as shown below when I try to run the code. It errors out on the line where I try to inject TimerEventHandler in startup.cs Here is the code:

```
public class TimerEventHandler : ITimerEventHandler
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly IHubContext<IndexHub> _hubContext;
    
        public TimerEventHandler(IHubContext<IndexHub> hubContext,
                                 IConfiguration config)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
            _config = config;            
        }
    }
```

ITimerEventHandler

```
public interface ITimerEventHandler
{
    Task OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e, string connectionId);
}
```

And here is code from my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{            
   services.AddSignalR(o =>
   {
      o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
   });
   services.AddScoped<ITimerEventHandler, TimerEventHandler>();            
}
```

Code from indexhub

```
public class IndexHub : Hub
{       

    private readonly IServiceBusHelper _serviceBusHelper;
    private readonly ITimerEventHandler _timerEventHandler;
    

    public IndexHub(IServiceBusHelper serviceBusHelper,
                  ITimerEventHandler timerEventHandler)
    {
        _serviceBusHelper = serviceBusHelper;
        _timerEventHandler = timerEventHandler;
    }
    ....

}
```

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
> System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: my.portal.Hubs.ITimerEventHandler Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: my.portal.Hubs.TimerEventHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext`1[my.portal.Hubs.IndexHub]' while attempting to activate 'my.portal.Hubs.TimerEventHandler'.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at my.portal.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 10
```

Can any of you experts out there help out?

Comment: By using your provided code,I could not reproduce your issue,it works well in my project.Could you share your `ITimerEventHandler` and `IndexHub`.Also from you error message,could you share your Program.cs?

Comment: @Rena Thanks for looking.  I've added the code as requested.

Comment: Sorry,what you provide is not what I want.I need `ITimerEventHandler ` and `IndexHub`.Not IndexHub.js.

Comment: Sorry @Rena.  I've added ITimerHandler and IndexHub now.

Comment: Also could work well in my project.Maybe some other things influence the project.Could you please create a new repos which could reproduce the issue?And I am a bit confused that why did you circular reference the ITimerEventHandler   and IndexHub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I figured it out! I had installed the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core package instead of Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core package. Thanks @Rena for looking at this. Just you getting me to look more closely at my code and try to strip it down to the basics helped me solve this.